# How to insert separate row for unique login count each day in database table

Tags: java, database, jdbc, struts

I am working on a struts based web application using postgresql DB. I need to display last 15 days of login history of my website login users as a bar chart for website admin. I have tried to generate a bar chart using JFreeChart library. It is taking two 
Database coloumns and creating a bar chart as a image on the fly(dynamically).
My problem is that I don't have any idea that how to store the count of unique login per day for last 15 days in database. Main problem is, it should maintain a new row for each new date
and the entries should be counted date-wise.

How to get the logic so that whenever date is changing it should go to insert a new row for each new date?
Any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that I don't have any idea that how to store the count
>   of unique login per day for last 15 days in database.

you may use SQL like below

```
select count(distinct username) 
from logintable 
where datediff(day,current_date(),datecolumn) < 15
group by datecolumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to store the count of unique logins each day, just insert a row for each login. You can then do the statistical analysis (eg counting, deciding what is unique) when you need to generate a report on it.

Comment: Hi Mark
I think your idea is nice and simple to implement. I am going to try for it.

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena And combined with the [answer of jdevelop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15038240/466862) you should have a simple idea how to get the data for you report